# img srcset doesn't scale down when viewport shrinks

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, srcset

I'm not sure if my understanding of the [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) attribute is wrong.

Given this html

```html
<img 
  srcset="
      /path/to/image1 343w,
      /path/to/image2 768w,
      /path/to/image3 304w" 
  sizes="
      (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 639px) 343px,
      (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 767px) 768px,
      (min-width: 768px) 304px"
/>
```

I thought that once I shrink my browser window from e.g. 700px width to 500px width the browser will switch the image from `/path/to/image2` to `/path/to/image1`. Is this not how it works?
Once my browser (tested with Chrome and Firefox) has loaded the larger image, it's not switching back to the smaller one.

My page layout changes from one breakpoint to the next, so I'd like to load an image with a different aspect ratio once the viewport width shrinks. Is the only way to do this through Javascript? Or should I use multiple image tags and set `display: none` for the inactive media queries?

Comment: The srcset-method lets browsers decide itself which image to show by providing the image-file-width. For your use-case, the <picture>-element is the right choice, where you can exactly define which image will be displayed for each MQ
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Answer (score 0):

Try using `height: auto;` in the css of the image.

Comment: `height: auto;` doesn't help and it seems to me that the `<picture>` element is indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [<picture>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element is what I was looking for. Thanks to @niorad.

I also found [this blog post](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/dont-use-picture-most-of-the-time/) explaining the differences between `<img>` and `<picture>`.